# Installing phpunit via Ansible

Tags: php, phpunit, vagrant, ansible

I'm attempting to install phpunit via ansible with a view to running it on a vagrant vm, however I keep receiving an error in the build process:

> Channel "pear.phpunit.de" is not initialized, use "pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de" to initializeor pear config-set auto_discover 1
>   unknown channel "pear.phpunit.de" in "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
>   invalid package name/package file "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
>   install failed

The ansbile config looks something like:

```
- name: Install phpunit
  command: pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
  command: pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
  command: pear channel-discover components.ez.no
  command: pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
  command: pear update-channels
  command: pear upgrade-all
  command: pear install pear.symfony.com/Yaml
  command: pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit 
  command: pear install --force --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

Has anyone managed to successfully get phpunit to install via ansible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the pear installer for PHPUnit is no longer supported. If you want to install PHPUnit with ansible you could do:

```
 get_url: url=https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar dest=/usr/local/bin/phpunit mode=555
```

Answer (score 1):

More infor about no longer supported PEAR installation method:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method

Russell's method works fine.

Comment: please don't just post links

Answer (score 0):

The playlist snippet you pasted is incorrect–it will only run the first command because you can't specify multiple commands in a single task. Try this list of tasks, instead:

```
 - command: pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
 - command: pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
 - command: pear channel-discover components.ez.no
 - command: pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
 - command: pear update-channels
 - command: pear upgrade-all
 - command: pear install pear.symfony.com/Yaml
 - command: pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit 
 - command: pear install --force --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

You don't need to specify a - name for every task, but you do have to use the hyphen before each command to signal to Ansible that this is a new task.